# Regex: Select all html links except one particular html link <a href="https://..." /></a>

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have more html links such as:

```
<a href="https://liber5fg.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/picture-183.jpg"><img loading="lazy" blah blah" /></a>
<a href="https://binterest68.wordpress.com/picture-183.jpg"><img loading="lazy" blah blah" /></a>
<a href="https://stevepeter.gono.com/picture-183.jpg"><img loading="lazy" blah blah" /></a>
<a href="https://sonarhut.com/bing0235644545.jpg"><img loading="lazy" blah blah" /></a>
```

I must use a regex to select/delete all links except the 3'th one with `<a href="https://stevepeter.gono.com...`

So, after find and replace, **the output should be:**

```
<a href="https://stevepeter.gono.com/picture-183.jpg"><img loading="lazy" blah blah" /></a>
```

I try this regex, but doesn't work too good:

FIND: `(?s)<a href="https://+\K(?!stevepeter).+</a>(?-s)`

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: @Gantendo From my experience, OP does not do parsers. They ask about Notepad++ regex here.

Comment: I edit the post. I try this regex, but doesn't work too good: FIND: `(?s)<a href="https://+\K(?!stevepeter).+</a>(?-s)`

Comment: thank you all, I fix the problem and I post the answer. Doesn't need any xml. And I recommend REGEX for repair many things in html static pages. So, only for static pages, REGEX can solve almost any problem.

Comment: @JustMe Check out https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?s)<a href="https://(?!stevepeter)(?-s).+</a>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to use this 2 generic formulas:

- Find what: `(?s)BSR(FR)(?-s).+ESR`

  **or**
- Find what: `BSR(FR).+(?s:(?=.*(ESR)))`
- **BSR** *Begin Region Start*
- **ESR** *End Search Region*
- **FR** *Find Regex*  (here you put the formula for exception, staring with `?!` )

**In your case generic formula can be implement like this:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<a href="https://(?!stevepeter).+(?s:(?=.*(</a>)))`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>